# Copy a folder with special requirement

Tags: server, directory, copy

I want to copy a folder from a server , but not all files .

e.g I have folder named xyz
                        | and contents of folders are as below :

```
abc.conf
mno.conf
pqr.conf
rfc.conf
and so on
```

And I want to copy whole folder except `abc.conf`
and `rfc.conf`. How can I do this ?

Comment: You forgot 1 thing: HOW do you copy these files?  scp? telnet? ftp? winscp? a browser? filezilla? Why not copy all and remove those 2 when done? Less hassle ;-)

Comment: Why can't you just delete the files after copying them, as @Rinzwind suggested?

Comment: I am using  scp to copy , It's just example I have long list of file for removing it from list. i.e. I just not have two file to delete from list.

Comment: @Avanibadheka and there you have a big problem. you will need to supply -all- the exceptions to `scp`. Not the correct tool when you need to type all the exceptions ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `rsync`, you can grab all files from a folder, excluding a certain list using this command:

```
rsync -a --exclude-from=path/to/excludes.txt myuser@myserver:/path/to/files/ .
```

Be sure that `path/to/excludes.txt` is a text file like so:

```
abc.conf
rfc.conf
moo.conf
cat.conf
...
```

Note that this excludes file is stored locally, so you must grab it from the server first if you don't have it.

Otherwise, such a task is not possible without heavy SCP mangling and shell scripting using `xargs` and the like.

Comment: That's correct , but if I have list of file to exclude at a time. I used your command for single file excluding.